# Merge items in nanoc

Tags: ruby, include, staticmatic, nested-includes, nanoc

I have been trying to use [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org) for generating a static website. I need to organize a complex arrangement pages I want to keep my content DRY.

How does the concept of includes or merges work within the nanoc system? I have read the docs but I can't seem to find what I want.

For example: how can I take two partial content items and merge them together into a new content item.

In [staticmatic](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/) you can do some like the following inside your page.

```
= partial('partials/shared/navigation')
```

How would a similar convention work within nanoc?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

nanoc’s author here.

In nanoc, partials are layouts. So, you could have `layouts/partials/shared/navigation.html` and then render that partial like this:

```
= render '/partials/shared/navigation'
```

For that to work, enable the Rendering helper first, by including it somewhere in the `lib/` dir (e.g. `lib/helpers.rb`):

```
include Nanoc3::Helpers::Rendering
```

For more information, check out the [layouts as partials](https://nanoc.ws/doc/items-and-layouts/#partials) section of the manual.

Hope this helps!

Comment: in 2018 I have this in my "helpers.rb" file: `use_helper Nanoc::Helpers::Rendering`